# Norm of Lagrange interpolation polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, interpolation

Let's consider function $f: E \rightarrow K$, where $E \subset \mathbb C$. Let's consider Lagrange interpolation of $f$ for $a_1, a_2,...,a_n \in E$:

$$L_nf(x) = \sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j)l_j(x)$$

where $l_j(x) = \prod_{k=0, k \neq j}^n\frac{x - a_k}{a_j - a_k}$

I want to prove that $\|L_n\| = \max_{x \in E}\sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x)|$.

**My work so far**

Let's write what is $\|L_nf\|$:

$$\|L_nf\| = \|\sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j) l_j(x)\| = \max|\sum_{j = 0}^n f(a_j)l_j(x)| \le \max \sum_{j = 0}^n |f(a_j)l_j(x)| \le$$

$$\le \max\sum_{j =0 }^n \|f\| |l_j(x)| = \|f\|\max\sum_{ j =0}^n|l_j(x)|$$

So we have fact, that:

$$\frac{\|L_n(f)\|}{\|f\|} \le \max\sum_{j=0}^n|l_j(x)|$$

So now to obtain equality, we need to find such function $f$, for which $\frac{\|L_n(f)\|}{\|f\|} = \max \sum_{j = 0}^n|l_j(x)|$. Could you please give me a hand in finding such example?

**My solution**

Let's denote $x_0$ as: $\max_{x \in E}\sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x)| = \sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x_0)|$

Let's choose $f(x_j) = \textrm{sgn}l_j(x_0)$. The problem with $\textrm{sgn}$ is its definition on set of complex numbers. I am going to understand it as: $\textrm{sgn}(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$. Then:
$$\|L_nf\| \ge |L_n(f)(x_0)|  = |\sum_{j = 0}^n \textrm{sgn}l_j(x_0) l_j(x_0)| = |\sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x_0)||$$

Now, since we only sum positive numbers (modules of complex number), we'll have that:

$$|\sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x_0)|| = \sum_{j = 0}^n |l_j(x_0)|$$

And that ends the proof

Comment: Given any $x$, can you choose $f$ with $||f|| = 1$ such that $| L_nf (x) | = \sum \limits_{j=0}^n |l_j(x)|$? Then use $||L_n f|| \ge |L_n f (x)|$ and take the supremum over all $x$

Comment: So can I just take $f \equiv 1$?

Comment: That wouldn't ensure $L_nf(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n |l_j(x)|$. You can try to choose adequate $\pm 1$ values for $f$

Comment: @charmd I think I came up with the solution. Could you please take a look at it and say what you think?

Comment: Sure, please post it as an answer so you can accept it later

Comment: I updated my question which contains the answer

Comment: You don't know whether $x_0$ as you defined it exists: the max may be a sup that is not reached. Under proper hypothesis (the $l_j$ are continuous and $|l_j(x)| \to +\infty$ as $|x| \to +\infty$), it really is a max so it works

Comment: Also, my previous comment about $\pm 1$ was misleading, I thought we were in $\mathbb{R}$. Your "interpretation" of sign is chosen correctly (beware of $x=0$ to define it properly obviously)